# Running Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox from Mac OS X; how to change resolution?

Tags: virtualbox, macosx, display-resolution

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox from Mac OS X and am having no problems running it. I'm just wondering how to change the screen resolution so that the virtualized Ubuntu software fits my computer screen. I used Host F to go to fullscreen mode, but there are black borders on the edges, and I'd just like to get rid of them. Thank you.

Comment: You may need the [Guest Additions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) to do so.